# Gradle Sync: Failed to resolve (library name)

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, gradle

I am trying to include a Library Project(Android Studio Project) another Android Studio Project(app). The Library project has an Activity, which I want to launch from my Application.

I am getting error during Gradle Sync.

I am getting these errors:

[image: I am getting these errors]

I have gone through other Stackoverflow questions.

I added the Library project *File->New->New Module->Import Gradle Project.*

I have made the following changes in my Library project.
I have added following line in library project's build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

I have commented ApplicationID.

In settings.gradle, I have added

```
include ":LibraryName"
```

In build.gradle of App, I have added

```
compile project(":LibraryName")
```

What am I missing here?

**Edit: Adding app's Build.gradle file**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.viga.nativeapp"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile project(":VimeoVideoPlayer")
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**Settings.gradle**

```
include ':app', ':VimeoVideoPlayer'
```

Comment: post your app gradle and settings gradle

Comment: @BhuvaneshBs: Added build.gradle. The settings.gradle has only the following line
 **include ':app', ':VimeoVideoPlayer'**

Comment: Post setting.gradle also

Comment: settings.gradle has only one line, I have posted it. Thanks

Comment: If you have VimoVideoPlayer in your project directory your initialization in correct. Then your error is from Vimeo library.

Comment: I have VimeoPlayer Library project in the directory. If I build the library project alone, it works.  But if i build it with app, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Altough all the .aar files were present in VimioVideoPlayer/libs folder, for some reason Gradle couldn't find them. To solve this, I manually added all the missing dependencies.

- Go to File→ new→ new module and select Import .jar/.aar Package
- Now browse to the VimeoVideoPlayer/Libs and add all of them to the project.

After this change few lines build.gradle of VimeoVideoPlayer.

Delete the following lines

```
compile(name: 'unitygvr', ext:'aar')
compile(name: 'gvr', ext:'aar')
compile(name: 'gvr-permissionsupport-release', ext:'aar')
compile(name: 'gvr-keyboard', ext:'aar')
compile(name: 'gvr-exoplayersupport-release', ext:'aar')
compile(name: 'exoplayer-r1.5.11', ext:'aar')
```

and add these lines

```
compile project(':unitygvr')
compile project(':gvr')
compile project(':gvr-permissionsupport-release')
compile project(':gvr-keyboard')
compile project(':gvr-exoplayersupport-release')
compile project(':exoplayer-r1.5.11')
```

That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to solve your problem is by adding the lib directory to the list of repositories in the top level build.gradle file.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'VimioVideoPlayer/libs'
        }
    }
}
```